# Set <img> alt tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know how to set an ALT tag on an `<img>` if I have the class or globally to all the images on the page, however how can I do it to a specific image that doesn't have an id or class? Can I use the parent DIV somehow to reference the image and add an alt tag?

```
<div id="table_processing">
    <img src="processing_report.gif"> Loading Report List...
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Check out how CSS selectors work, and you can apply that with `querySelector` to target your element

Comment: You can use any CSS selector you want.

Comment: `document.querySelector('img[src="processing_report.gif"]').setAttribute('alt', '<altText>')`;

Comment: [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), [`ParentNode.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), [`ParentNode.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

Comment: @baao handing out answers like that only enables these questions. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use jQuery, you could use the ID from the parent element like this:

```
$('#table_processing img').attr('alt', 'your text here');
```

This "css selector" will get all images inside the div with the id "table_processing" and sets the alt tag.

Comment: That exactly what I was looking for, didn't realize you could reference the parent DIV like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend using `document.querySelector()`, which allows you to select the image using CSS (jQuery-like) selectors.

Like this:

```
var image = document.querySelector("#table_processing img");
```

and then you can set the `alt` attribute with:

```
image.alt = "Our New Alt Text";
```

or

```
image.setAttribute("alt", "our New Alt Text");
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var image = document.querySelector("#table_processing img");

image.alt = "Our New Alt Text";
```

```html
<div id="table_processing">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"> Loading Report List...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure/True/Real/Faster **JavaScript** Solution:

```
function setAlt()
{
    var div = document.querySelector("#table-processing");
        var image = div.querySelector("img");
            image.setAttribute("alt", "something");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery allows you to use valid css selector, so you can use this:

```
$('#table_processing img').attr('alt', <text>);
```

Comment: Teach! Answering questions is to teach the asker! What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to keep plugging jQuery, but here is a very good example of automating missing alt tags with generic info, this is something I do to patch for WCAG AA compliance until we can edit all the content.

```
$("img:not([alt])").attr({ alt: "your alt text", role: "presentation" });
$("iframe:not([title])").attr({ title: "your iframe title" });
```

This looks for images without alt attributes, adds it and adds the value "your alt text here" along with a role for screen readers, but you can remove that. IO. also do the same for iframes and embeds that may be third parties that are out of compliance.